# Help with finding the basis of a polynomial set

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

let $U = \{p \in P_4(F) : p(2) = p(5)\}$. find a basis of $U$

this is what i tried:
\begin{align*}
p(x) &= ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e\\
p(2) &= p(5)\\
a16 + b8 + c4 + d2 + e &= a625 + b125 + c25 + d4 + e\\
609a + 117b + 21c + 3d &= 0\\
d &= -609a/3 - 117b/3 - 21c/3\\
d &= -203a - 39b - 7c\\
p(x) &= ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + (-203a - 39b - 7c)x + e\\
p(x) &= a(x^4 - 203^x) + b(x^3 -39x) + c(x^2 -7x) + e\\
\end{align*}

basis: $\{(x^3 - 203), (x^2 -39), (x - 7), (1)\}$

is that correct? it's my first time reading a linear algebra book (linear algebra done right), having a bit of trouble with the exercises, thanks for any help :), sorry for any mistakes in nomenclature.

Comment: It looks good but a couple of comments:  Something like "x3" is ambiguous- the "3" could be an exponent or an index.  For an exponent use "x^3" (and for an index "x_3
"_).  Second, a basis is SET of vectors.  I would include those vectors in "{  }".

Comment: Thanks for the help and the tip :)

Comment: Welcome to math.se. You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. I made some initial edits to the formatting; feel free to make further improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, but you shouldn't have taken the factor of $x$ out of each term. This is because $x$ is not an element of the base field, thus you can't treat it as a coefficient, but rather, think of it as a vector.

As you correctly pointed out, $U$ consists of all polynomials of the form:
$$p(x) = a(x^4-203x)+b(x^3-39x)+c(x^2-7x)+e$$

This means that $U = \text{Span}(x^4-203x, x^3-39x,x^2-7, 1)$. Now you need to check wheter this vectors are linearly independent (Hint: use the fact that they have different degrees) and conclude the argument!

Comment: Thanks!, I will try to conclude the argument.